# Parse xml fragment based on attribute value using Spring batch

Tags: java, xml-parsing, spring-batch

I want to parse xml based on attribute value using spring batch below is XML for reference.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customerInfo>
<cutommer dept="IT">
<param value="Jane" name="first-name"/> 
<param value="Doe" name="last-name"/>
<param value="17 Streets" name="address"/> 
<param value="1234567" name="phone-number"/>
</customer>
<cutommer dept="ES">
<param value="Jane" name="first-name"/> 
<param value="Doe" name="last-name"/>
<param value="17 Streets" name="address"/> 
<param value="1234567" name="phone-number"/>
</customer>
</customerInfo>
```

Base on above xml want to parse only Customer tag which dept atribute value is "IT".Any help is appriciated

Update 1:

```
    @Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class ControllerInfoParser_Config extends DefaultBatchConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobs;
    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory steps;
    @Bean
    public Job parseComponentInfoXML(Step parseComponentInfo,Step partitionStep, CustomJobExecutionerListener customJobExecutionerListener)
            throws UnexpectedInputException, ParseException, Exception {

        return jobs.get("parseComponentInfoXML").listener(customJobExecutionerListener).start(parseComponentInfo)
                .next(partitionStep).build();


    }
    @Bean
    public Step parseComponentInfo(ItemReader<Customer> oneDeptITItemReader) throws UnexpectedInputException, ParseException, Exception {

        return steps.get("parseComponentInfo").<Customer, Customer> chunk(1)
                .reader(componentInfoReader()).reader(oneDeptITItemReader).processor(componentInfoProcessor())
                .writer(componentInfoWriter()).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemReader<Customer> componentInfoReader() throws UnexpectedInputException, ParseException, Exception {

       //OneDeptITItemReader <Customer> reader1 = new OneDeptITItemReader<Customer>();
        StaxEventItemReader<Customer> reader = new StaxEventItemReader<Customer>();
        reader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("xml//customer.xml"));
        reader.setFragmentRootElementName("customer");

        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller();
        marshaller.setClassesToBeBound(Customer.class);

      //  marshaller.setSchema(new ClassPathResource("xml//company.xsd"));

        reader.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);

        return reader;
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemReader<Customer> oneDeptITItemReader(ItemReader<Customer> ir) {
        OneDeptITItemReader<Customer> odIR = new OneDeptITItemReader<Customer>();
        odIR.setDelegate(ir);
        return odIR;
    }
    @Bean
    public ItemProcessor<Customer, Customer> componentInfoProcessor() {

        return new CustomerProcessor();
    }

     @Bean
    public ItemWriter<Object>  componentInfoWriter() {

        return new SqlWritter();
    }
}

public class OneDeptITItemReader <T>  implements  ItemReader <Customer>{

    ItemReader<Customer> delegate;

      public ItemReader<Customer> getDelegate() {
        return delegate;
    }

    public void setDelegate(ItemReader<Customer> delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    public Customer read() {
        boolean read = true;
        Customer item = null;
        while(read)  {
          try {
            item = delegate.read();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            read =false;
        }
         read = !"IT".equals(item.getDept());
        }
        return item;
      }

}
```

Comment: Don't focus on read but on process phase: with a custom `ItemProcessor<Customer, Customer>` return null if dept <> "IT" or return object itself if dept is equals to "IT"

Comment: Thanks Luca for suggestion,earlier I thought about this approach but my XML file will be huge around 15 MB and it contain only one fragment which dept attribute value is "IT", and remaining thousands of customer fragment will unnecessary get parse and come to ItemProcessor. Is there a  way we can stop further batch process once we get customer fragment with IT dept to avoid unnecessary consumption of resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to stop reading is to return `null` from `ItemReader.read()`.
Write a custom ItemReader delegate and stop reading after an "IT" dept is found.

```
class OneDeptITItemReader implements ItemReader<Customer> {
  ItemReader<Customer> delegate;

  @Override
  public Customer read() {
    boolean read = true;
    while(read)  {
     Customer item = delegate.read();
     read = read != null && !"IT".equals(item.getDept());
    }
    return item;
  }
}
```

When using delegation you have to register delegated reader as stream to let SB manage its lifecycle.
See [6.5 The Delegate Pattern and Registering with the Step](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html#delegatePatternAndRegistering)

Comment: Thanks Luca for sharing snippet,I tried above code but getting null pointer exception while calling delegate.read().

Comment: I suppose you setted a valid delegate before call my code snippet.

Comment: I have put implementation details in question see update 1 : let me know if any thing need to change.

Comment: I don't know how javaconfig works. I forgot to write about stream registration. Check my edit

Answer (score 0):

Below snippet work for me.

The way to stop reading is to return null from ItemReader.read().
Write a custom ItemReader delegate and stop reading after an "IT" dept is found.

```
class OneDeptITItemReader implements ItemReader<Customer> {
StaxEventItemReader<Customer> delegate;

public void setDelegate(StaxEventItemReader<Customer> delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

  @Override
  public Customer read() {
    boolean read = true;
   delegate.open(new ExecutionContext ());
   Customer item = null;
    while(read)  {
     item = delegate.read();
     read = item != null && !"IT".equals(item.getDept());
    }
    return item;
  }
}
```